# Prevent jQuery append from closing tags

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

After an Ajax call I want to append the HTML code in the container. I do this with

```
$(".item:last").append(data.html);
```

However, it happens that an element first closes and reopens some div containers. As jQuery tries to close the tags it inserts me a wrong HTML code.

How can I prevent this from happening?

I found the tip here to insert the code inside a DIV container:

```
$(".item:last").append($('<div>').html(data.html));
```

Since I use bootstrap the div is interpreted to me as a container and my design is destroyed.

Is there another possibility?

A simplified example:

Normally my HTML code is for pasting:

```
<div class="firstClass1">
    <div class="firstClass2">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

But sometimes it is this:

```
</div>
</div>
<div class="newClass1">
    <div class="newClass2">
        <div class="firstClass1">
            <div class="firstClass2">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
```

The closing DIV's are removed by append.

EDIT2: console.log of data.html

```
<div class="col item">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
            <h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


// START SPECIAL
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="next-part">
    <h1 class="group-title">CONTENT</h1>
        <div class="row border">
            <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-2 row-cols-3xl-3 g-4">
//END SPECIAL
    
<div class="col item">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
            <h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using $(selector).html(...) without $(selector).append(...) ? Is the content you intend to insert with jquery formatted correctly? Does every opening tag have the closing one? Furthermore, before inserting html code inside a div it would be right to remove the previous content with $(selector).html();

Comment: Thanks. With html I am missing the closing tags too. At the end of append (infinity scoll) the last DIV tags are closed. EDIT: No. My goal is not to insert correctly formatted code since the closing tags will be inserted later without JS.

Comment: @Koda I don't think it's appand or html that "removes" the last closing tag, but something in your html. I would console.log(data) and check if everything is okay. remember to check that you have a startin `"` and end `"` for everything like class, attr, id

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have included a console.log above. The three closing tags are in data.html but are missing afterwards when I check the code in the development console

Comment: @Koda Could you show us the exact content of data.html ? So as returned from the ajax call?

Comment: @Alex I have created a codeply here with which it is reproducible. If I paste the HTML code directly the design is correct: https://www.codeply.com/p/zRPrJrSYRz
Does this help?

Comment: You can't and should not have ending tags in your code that has no starting tag. This will make lots of problems for you

Comment: My problem is that I have to adjust the design in an Infinity Scoll when certain parameters change. Therefore I do not get around there. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Browsers correct invalid html based on best effort. I guess that's what happening and that it's not jQuery's doing this. That said, I'm pretty sure that there will be a way to change the design of your infinite scroll without appending invalid html. I can't tell how because the question contains to little information to figure that out.

Comment: Your issue is that you are thinking `.append` changes the HTML string.  It doesn't.  It appends HTML to the DOM.  The DOM cannot contain incomplete/partial "HTML strings".  You're not manipulating the HTML itself, you're adding HTML to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have incorrect html (you have a `</div>` to much at the end) of your current html.

If you can change the data.html result, then you can remove the 3 x `</div>` and do `$('.next-part').after`

**Demo**

```js
$('.next-part').after('<div class="next-part"><h1 class="group-title">CONTENT 2</h1><div class="row border"><div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-2 row-cols-3xl-3 g-4"><div class="col item"><div class="card"><div class="card-body"><p>CONTENT</p><h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5></div></div></div><div class="col item"><div class="card"><div class="card-body"><p>CONTENT</p><h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5></div></div></div><div class="col item"><div class="card"><div class="card-body"><p>CONTENT</p><h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5></div></div></div><div class="col item"><div class="card"><div class="card-body"><p>CONTENT</p><h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5></div></div></div>');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="next-part">
  <h1 class="group-title">CONTENT 1</h1>
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-2 row-cols-3xl-3 g-4">
      <div class="col item">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
            <h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col item">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
            <h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col item">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
            <h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col item">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
            <h5 class="card-title">CONTENT</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```